# Input Field that creates Tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to create an input field that people can type their skills into. When it's displayed on the front end of the site, each skill will be it's own element. So I'd like users to type their skills like this:

> skill 1, skill 2, skill 3

and on the front end of the site, it should show like this:

[Skill 1] [Skill 2] [Skill 3].

So the **comma** separates each skill
 and then each skill will have some styling applied to it in CSS.

I've tried a few different techniques but non seem to work how I want them to, if someone could help me out here, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: What did you try. Any code?

Answer (score 6):

Not without JavaScript (added the tags to your Question)
This example will allow you to continuously write your *skills*, while hitting <kbd>,</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> to 'divide' them.

[image: Tags generator like stackoverflow]

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  $('#tags input').on('focusout', function() {
    var txt = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\+\-\.\#]/g, ''); // allowed characters list
    if (txt) $(this).before('<span class="tag">' + txt + '</span>');
    this.value = "";
    this.focus();
  }).on('keyup', function(e) {
    // comma|enter (add more keyCodes delimited with | pipe)
    if (/(188|13)/.test(e.which)) $(this).trigger('focusout');
  });

  $('#tags').on('click', '.tag', function() {
    if (confirm("Really delete this tag?")) $(this).remove();
  });

});
```

```css
#tags {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 4px;
  font-family: Arial;
}

#tags span.tag {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  color: #555;
  background: #add;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  margin: 4px;
}

#tags span.tag:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

#tags span.tag:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "×";
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 0 4px;
  margin: 3px 0 10px 7px;
  font-size: 10px;
}

#tags input {
  background: #eee;
  border: 0;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 7px;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
Add a skill and hit [,] or [Tab] or [Enter]<br><br>

<div id="tags">
  <span class="tag">Photoshop</span>
  <span class="tag">Illustrator</span>
  <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Add a skill" />
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is pretty helpful!

Comment: How to remove `,` from the list leaving just `tab` and `enter` as valid

Answer (score 1):

Would you like to try this http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/?

This is tags editor jquery plugin, simmilar to stackoverflow tags. I think, it is pretty nice. But in terms of your problem you would need some customizations.

Comment: Once that page goes offline/down your answer will be of no-help to anyone.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using client side scripting, 
use jquery function split() the value with comma(',') to an array then append a css class to each array variable and display it.

```
var raw_data = "skill 1, skill 2, skill 3";
data_array = raw_data .split(",");
```

can access the elements by `data_array[0]`,`data_array[1]` and `data_array[2]`

add or append these values to input field or  html elements with `.css( "color", "red" )`